# Getting transform.Translate behavior using Rigidbodys in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

My goal is to achieve behavior that is exactly like `tranform.Translate()`, just without breaking collision detection. I'm currently dealing with some rather thin walls and the GameObject (using the "Continuous" collision detection mode) will pass through the walls whether I use `transform.Translate()` or `Rigidbody.MovePosition()` . The ONLY way I have been able to fix this is by using something like `rbody.AddForce(force, ForceMode.VelocityChange)`, however, this now produces "slidey" behavior. Does anyone know how I can achieve the behavior of transform.Translate while maintaining accurate collision?

EDIT: I tried adjusting rbody.velocity directly, but now there is another issue. When moving into a wall at an angle, the GameObject will completely halt. The desired behavior is for the GameObject to move where it's able to. [(see attached image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQPio.png)

Comment: `Transform.Translate` and `Rigidbody.MovePosition` both do not check for collision at all. If you want a collision simulation, you must either use the physics themselves (like with `Rigidbody.AddForce`) or do a ray cast yourself.

Comment: Okay, that was already addressed in the post. I'm looking for the behavior of `Transform.Translate` but the collision detection provided by `Rigidbody.AddForce`.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between "slidey" behaviour and your desired behaviour?

Comment: maybe you find [rigidbody constraints](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.html) useful

Comment: @SvenViking Someone walking as you would see everyday is the desired behavior. The actual behavior is as if the GameObject were moving on ice skates. I can provide a video clip if you need.

Comment: And it’s not just that the speed is wrong?

Comment: @SvenViking When using rbody.AddForce(force, ForceMode.VelocityChange) the velocity increases without bound, so without further calculation the speed would also be wrong in this case. So while the speed IS wrong, that is not the only problem.

Comment: Added an answer describing how to move a Rigidbody at a constant speed.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain what I would try (don't know if it works).
I would have the Rigidbody in a parent GameObject of the game object of interest. In the `OnCollisionEnter` of this parent GameObject I would have some logic that gives this parent GameObject the same rotation as the wall is colliding with and the inverted rotation to the child go so that you have the child not rotated at all and the parent GameObject aligned with the wall. By aligned I mean both with their local axis at the same rotation.
Then with either [Rigidbody constraint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.html) or moving the transform you should be able to move the parent GameObject along the plane of the wall, as you aligned the axis system with the one of the wall in the logic I mentioned.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it seems what you're wanting is to be able to move the Rigidbody at a constant speed. For 3D movement you can use something like this:

```cs
Vector3 targetVelocity = Vector3.forward * moveSpeed;
rigidbody.AddRelativeForce((targetVelocity - rigidbody.velocity), ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

For 2D movement you can use something like this:

```cs
Vector3 v = rigidbody.velocity;
v.x = moveSpeed;
```

(Both in `FixedUpdate()`.) This should move the object at a constant velocity equal to `moveSpeed` without bypassing collision detection.